# .Net Core - Policy based authorization returning 500 on failed authorization

Tags: api, asp.net-core, authorization

I've set up a simple policy based authorization for testing purposes. The authorization works, as it breaks inside the handler. If I set the test authorization to pass, I'm allowed to access the controller endpoint I set to use the TestPolicy. However, if I set it to fail like in the code snippet below, the authorization fails, but I get a 500-response where clearly a 401 or 403 would be appropriate.

I'm fairly sure it's because the API doesn't have any form of authentication. But I do not want to implement any authentication in this API, as all calls to it should be treated as if they are authenticated. Roles etc. will be fetched through the httpcontext. Does anyone know how I can address this problem without requiring the API consumer to authenticate themselves?

The test code is below. The parameter to new TestRequirement() can be changed to test passing/failing authorization easily.

```
public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
     services.AddAuthorization(options =>
     {
         options.AddPolicy("TestPolicy",
            policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TestRequirement(false)));
     });

     services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TestHandler>();

     //<snip>
}

public class TestHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TestRequirement>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TestRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (requirement.Passes)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
            
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class TestRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public bool Passes { get; }

    public TestRequirement(bool shouldPass)
    {
        this.Passes = shouldPass;
    }
}
```

Edit: I ended up making a custom authenticationhandler, like this:

```
public class AuthenticationSchemeHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
{
    private HttpContext httpContext;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        properties ??= new AuthenticationProperties();
        this.httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task ForbidAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        properties ??= new AuthenticationProperties();
        this.httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
    {
        this.httpContext = context;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

It seems to work (although it feels kinda wrong to implement and use authentication when I don't actually authenticate anything), however when my testhandler fails, it'll call the challengeasync instead of forbidasync. From my understanding challengeasync is for when you do not know the user and need to verify them, while forbidasync is when the use is unauthorized. So just scratching my head a bit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. A challenge result should generally be used in cases where the current visitor is not logged in, but is trying to access an action that requires an authenticated user. It will prompt a challenge for credentials. It could also be used for an authenticated user, who is not authorised for the action, and where you want to prompt for higher privileged credentials. A forbid result should be used in cases where the current visitor is logged in as a user in your system, but is trying to access an action that their account does not have permission to perform.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thanks for the confirmation. The issue is I never actually authenticate anyone. So in the end it's okay that it uses a challenge, I guess. I'm just unsure how I can make a forbid trigger. I've not been able to do that yet. Is it something that automatically happens if a policy fails and the user has been authenticated?